# Insert strings into JSON template

Tags: c++, json, templates, c++11

I know there are JSON parsers but this seems so simple so I could do a diy approach.

```
std::string item_name
std::string item_address

itemname = "John";
item_address = "New York";

{"item": {"name": "std::cout << item_name", "address": "std::cout << item_address"}}
```

I want to have a rigid JSON template which I insert my values into. The approach above seems like it's wrong.

Should I use templates? Can anyone tell me how I might start implementing something like this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this ?

```
std::cout << "{'item': {'name': '" << item_name << 
    "', 'address': '" << item_address << "'}}";
```

It's a bit ugly to say the least. Consider using like [boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) instead.

Demo with boost::format:

```
std::string result = str(
    boost::format("{'item': {'name': '%1%', 'address': '%2%'}}") 
    % item_name % item_address);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I could use boost, although I would still prefer an approach which didn't require it

Comment: Unfortunately, regular streams are probably your best bet then.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not scared of using a library you could consider [mustache](https://github.com/mrtazz/plustache). This is of course very powerful, maybe a little over the top...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there not a clean and simple way it your having to use a lib? I would rather avoid libs where possible